# ForEach Boto3 Equivalant

Tags: foreach, boto3

I would like to iterate through this list of users and in place "variable" below, run the function three times, each time replacing variable with bob, fred, and then nancy.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('iam')

users = ['bob', 'fred', 'nancy']

for user in users:

    client.create_user(
        UserName='variable'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('iam')

users = ['bob', 'fred', 'nancy']

for user in users:
    client.create_user(
        UserName = (user)
        )
```